# Chrome Extension - Find out if extension tab is open

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have set up that when I click extn icon - my extn `index.html` opens.
If I click the icon a second time - I don't want it to open a second tab; I want it to focus the already open tab (if it's open).

The problem is with `if it's open` part. Ideally, I would not want to ask for a `tabs` permission, as it is very intrusive. Because of this restriction I cannot iterate all the open tabs and check their urls.
I tried storing extn tab id in `chrome.local.storage` and checking for it when I click the extn button - but always maintaining up-to-date tab number proved to be rather difficult. The ultimate obstacle was that when Chrome is closed - it doesnt fire any type of `onClose` event; thus I cannot clear local storage of now obsolete extn tab id.
So, when I reopen Chrome, click extn button - it will not open the new tab because it can see the old tab id in the storage and thinks that a tab is already open.

Is there any way to achieve the result w\o the `tabs` permission?

Comment: I don't think so, a limited, less powerful tabs api would be nice. Like for opening new extension page tabs or accessing current extension page tab like what you need.
I guess an ugly workaround would be to save a "last_open" key every second or so when the index.html is open. When you open a new one you can check if the last_open was less than a second ago and close it. The focus part won't  work this way though, I don't think that is possible without the tabs api.

Comment: It is possible, see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For embedded options shown in `chrome://extensions` UI you can simply use [chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage) which will take care of refocusing the existing tab.

To find a standalone tab of your own extension use [chrome.extension.getViews()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) and [chrome.tabs.getCurrent()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent) invoked on the other tab's JS `window` to get its own "current" tab:

```js
function getOwnTabs() {
  return Promise.all(
    chrome.extension.getViews({type: 'tab'})
      .map(view =>
        new Promise(resolve =>
          view.chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab =>
            resolve(Object.assign(tab, {url: view.location.href}))))));
}

async function openOptions(url) {
  const ownTabs = await getOwnTabs();
  const tab = ownTabs.find(tab => tab.url.includes(url));
  if (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true});
  } else {
    chrome.tabs.create({url});
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
openOptions('index.html')
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you! Although, I never mentioned that I needed to access the options page. I actually need `index.html`. Still working great.

Comment: Question: How come it does not need the extension id? If I would code it via `chrome.tabs.query` I would need to fetch the full url with `chrome.extension.getURL("index.html")` first.

Comment: And a 2nd question: Why is `url` present on `ownTabs.find(tab => tab.url`? I thought it was only present with `tabs` permission.

Comment: The relative paths are resolved to the extension origin automatically. I forgot about the URL thing, updated the code.

Comment: The funny thing is: `url` was indeed present on `tab` object, event w\o the `tabs` persmission. Do you have any idea as to why?

Comment: Obviously because it's a same-origin URL. I don't know though why query() doesn't include it, but I'd say the latter is a bug, see https://crbug.com/1045813

Comment: Hi!, would you plz look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73109017/11974735 I cant figure out how this code can be modified to solve my problem...