# Check whether an URL is already open or not in Background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, if-statement, tabs

I send message using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({});` from my `content.js` and it is received by background script which opens a HTML file:

### background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'popup.html'});
});
```

If the `popup.html` is already open, I don't want to open it again, so there should be a `if`condition to check whether it is already open.

But what do I put in side the `if` condition before `chrome.tabs.create({url: 'popup.html'});` in the background script?

Please note that I am looking the solution inside banckground script.

Please provide the solution according to the scripts given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72781564/11974735).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check every tab if your extension popup page opened

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var flag = false;
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (let index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
            const tab = tabs[index];
            if (tab.url.includes("chrome-extension://")) { //You can filter by extension id or popup.html if you want
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'err.html' });
        }
        else{
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'popup.html' });
        }
    });
});
```

You can filter by extension id or popup.html if you want in `if (tab.url.includes("chrome-extension://")) {`. For better results you can filter by your extension id

err.html

```
<html>
    <script src="err.js"></script>
</html>
```

err.js

```
alert("Popup already opened");
window.close();
```

if popup tab already opened then open err.html and show alert then close. But you can't alert in `background.js` because `background.js` does not have a page to show alert.

You can see your extension id from extension details in chrome and popup url. "Kimlik" means ID btw.

And I mean when you open a new tab with using your extension it will always includes your extension id in url so you can filter your url by it.

[image: extension id]

[image: popup url]

example code:

```
if (tab.url.includes("chrome-extension://elbpcoenaghkeppoliiaakgggojafnkl/popup.html")) { 
    flag = true;
}
```

or you can use `chrome.runtime.id` to get extension id

[image: chrome.runtime.id]

Comment: It appears to take  considerable space and time, is it the most efficient way? Or is there a built-in function instead of running a loop?

Comment: If you don’t want to create new page you can use notifications and When I lookup for this solution I didn’t see or come to mind. And I think there is no method for checking popup tab from chrome own library. You can maybe assign an id to popup tab and if id still exist don’t open popup page but still its same thing

Comment: Would you kindly show examples of `filter by extension id or popup.html `, how do I get id? What do you mean by `can filter by extension id or popup.html `, please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a lot simpler to **store the `id` of the opened tab**, set that `id` to null if the tab is closed, and only open another new tab if no open tab `id` is set.

You can use the [second argument](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create-callback) of `chrome.tabs.create` for this. Watch for when the tab is removed using `chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener`.

*I didn't find time to do the setup to run this code. I'll update this later but perhaps it already helps out.*

```
let popupTabId = null;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (popupTabId !== null) {
        // Optionally do stuff with the existing tab here. 
        return;
    }
    chrome.tabs.create(
        {url: 'popup.html'},
        tab => {
            popupTabId = tab.id;
        }
    );
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(
    removedTabId => {
        if (removedTabId === popupTabId) {
            popupTabId = null;
        }
    }
)
```

You can also [focus the tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225964/is-there-a-way-to-focus-on-a-specific-tab-in-chrome-via-plugin) using its `id` in the listener. I only added a return statement in the code as strictly the question is only for detecting the tab.

#### Handling open tabs on extension startup

*If the popup tab is always closed when/before Chrome exits, you can ignore the following and the above solution should be sufficient.*

My solution doesn't handle tabs that are already opened yet, when the extension initializes. For this you could use the slower solution of the other answer to initialize the value of `popupTabId` to something else than `null`.

Another option is to [write the tab `id` to storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) when it changes, then read it on initialization.